# Visual C++ 2010 code completion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've been using c# for a while and I've noticed it had code prediction for your code and "resolves" for `using`'s to functions.  I'm working with visual c++ now and I noticed it has no code prediction and it doesn't have any "resolve" to any missing `include`.

Is this a setting you have to enable in visual c++? Or do you have to know what include you need for the included functions?

*I'm just curious I've learned C and IDE's for C don't have code prediction.  I'm now learning c++ and I was curious to see if visual c++ had code prediction or smart include resolutions.*

Thanks Stack, my favorite site!

Comment: Visual C++ does have code prediction ("Intellisense") in native C++ projects, and it got much better in VS2010.  However "Intellisense" got disabled on C++/CLI projects in VS2010, because the improvements weren't compatible.  However [Microsoft has promised](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx) that Intellisense for C++/CLI will be back in the next release of Visual Studio, and better than ever.

Comment: Wow so we won't see Intellisense in VS2010?  :( Or will it be a service pack update? (I read from the link provided that it won't even be provided in a service pack... but idk.) Thanks for letting me know about Intellisense though. I didn't know that's what it was.

Comment: Intellisense is alive and working great for native C++ code.  C++/CLI Intellisense will be brought back in an update, and it now looks like that means "new version" and not "service pack", but only MS can say for sure.  VA-X is an excellent tool that not only fills in the missing pieces but makes them even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get all the Intellisense features in VC++ that you get in C# or other managed languages.

I would recommend getting [Visual Assist from Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/) as this considerably improves the IDE. You can check out a free eval copy I think.

Comment: VA-X is a very good recommendation.  It provides Intellisense improvements for both native code and C++/CLI, even on VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

See the following link where this issue is discussed by others including Microsoft.  It seems that support was not included for the current release.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501921/c-cli-intellisense

Comment: Be sure to differentiate native C++ and C++/CLI.  Intellisense is supported very well for native C++ in VS2010.

Comment: Intellisense was obviously beyond repair, so Microsoft bought support for **real** C++ from EDG. This works **very well** for native code, but has no support for that other language.